# MapView shows blank google maps on debug build

Tags: react-native, google-maps, expo, android-mapview, eas

I am new to React Native, I have a managed Expo workflow and want to build just for preview with EAS and as Expo docs say -
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/
I need an API key restricted to Android apps, Maps SDK for Android enabled, package name and a debug keystore fingerprint which is the same for all Expo debug builds - 5E:8F:16:06:2E:A3:CD:2C:4A:0D:54:78:76:BA:A6:F3:8C:AB:F6:25 -
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/#how-to-retrieve-your-debug-keystore-fingerprint

[image]

Also configured app.json as the docs say
[image]

I have a very slow 32bit windows pc so I am not able to install Android Studio to generate SHA-1 fingerprint myself, if I omit API key in app.json - the build crashes instantly when app loads, but with the API key included even with some random string -  app opens but maps are blank with just google logo on it, with Expo Go everything works fine, I do not know what to do next, my guess is that the API key is not valid, but I have no ides why.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as you. Did you solved it,

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I have similar issue - Blank google map on android device after deploy via Expo with command - 'eas build --profile preview --platform android'. I lost so many hours with RN Expo build and finally found solution -
SHA1 key which you insert to google panel **you should get from your Expo panel** 'https://expo.dev/accounts/[YOUR_ACC_NAME]' -> project name -> Credentials -> Click and will get page like this where you get SHA1 key [image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the google map api entry in your "AndroidManifest.xml", something like this:

```
<meta-data 
   android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
   android:value="mygooglemapapikey"/>
```